# open source tool to automate the process of installing Adobe applications on Mac

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, open-source

we are trying to automate the process of downloading app and installing the same on Mac. Currently we are using Selenium till downloading app, for installation we are finding difficulty to handle, since we are trying to Install Adobe Application whic will be installed thru Adobe Installers, we are not able to inspect the elements thru Automator, Xcode etc..

Also while installing app, i need to track the status of progress too.
Pls suggest best open source tool for the above requirement on Mac.

Comment: Are you doing this for testing purposes? Or more for like system provision purposes?

Comment: How is this question different from http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3767/automating-installation-of-application-in-mac?  Are you trying to test the installer or do you just want an automatic way to install Adobe applications on the Mac?  If the latter, this excellent link may help you: http://bit.ly/Pgs1xv

Comment: am a part of Automation Testing, I want an Automatic way to install the app but not silently, I should be able to see the installation and also if there are any add-ons i need to check the progress of Installation as well as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I think AutoIt is for Windows only. For a Mac OSX native solution you could look into Automator. http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've run into a similar issue. On windows I just wrote something in [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to take over after selenium verified the download was available and downloaded it.

I found a similar question for something similar to AutoIt with some promising answers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485254/equivalent-of-autoit-for-mac-os-x

I hope it gets you what you're looking for.